# Designing a web-application: where should business logic reside?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, tomcat

There is a design of a web application that I am not sure how to evaluate as good or bad.
The idea is the following:
You have a web application (non-trivial) deployed in Tomcat that accepts client requests. The load could be as much Tomcat can handle I guess.
Now the actual processing is not done inside the container but delegated to another process which it connects via a single `TCP` connection. So what essentially happens here is multiplexing.
I.e. client requests are send concurrently by clients and these requests are send as messages to the other process to handle (the process itself I guess would be multithreading) but *over one connection*.
I have listen from a collegue about similar design (in another platform) that is very good in performance, but from my point of view this has a bottleneck in the usage of that single TCP connection.
Although I am experienced in multithreading, I don't really know or have used asynchronous approaches (nio etc) and I was wondering if this fits into this category.
Has anyone used multiplexing as part of a big project (this way at least)? Is it a good option?

Comment: I don't think opening more tcp connections between two machines will increase throughput; it probably will hurt throughput. so one connection is better. of course, that requires some careful design.

Comment: @irreputable:You have a point.But if you have a really big load from clients, multiplexing over the same connection would save resources, but would it be adequately fast to respond?

Comment: @irreputable:Also, ok not 1 but what about 3? Or exactly 4?How can such a number be determined at design time?Obviously you can not do performance tests and refactor after the implementation is done, in such a case as here

Comment: if it is a good choice for connecting to databases - when accurately tuned - I don't see why connection pooling would not be a good idea in your architecture

Comment: ...and if i am correct saying that the tcp connection is a kind of message bus, its implementation should actually be hidden in a library behind an api, and maybe interchangeable with other libraries

Comment: all connections share the same physical infrastructure that is serial in nature. think about a similar problem: if you have only 1 CPU, can you make a faster program by using more threads (suppose all computations are non blocking)?

Comment: @irreputable:I see what you are saying but on the other hand we don't treat each client request from the same thread arguing that the outgoing messages will be serialized anyway

Comment: @irreputable obviously not; but i assumed the backend model process is multithreaded in computing incoming messages and you can reasonbly expect some kind of blockiness there

Comment: between each client (a user at home) and the server, 1 connection for all requests would be the best choice - if the wiring protocol is designed properly. the http protocol wasn't design with that in mind, a connection is constantly blocked for a specific response. SPDY fixes that by multiplexing on 1 connection. so will the next http 2.0 protocol.

Comment: @guido:I think you are right it serves as a bus.But the result is not interchangeable with another library

Comment: @irreputable:But with `HTTP1.1` a client is expected to reuse the same connection.So what would multiplexing offer?Additionally multiplexing is already part of `HTTP1.1` but *no* browser currently supports it

Comment: @irreputable afaik SPDY multiplexes resources which have dependencies each other (sub-resources composing a webpage) and come from the same client. In this case the controller should not be seen as a single client, but wrapping the set of clients for which it accepted connections; and there no inter-dependencies among them

Comment: @Cratylus http/1.1 has pipelining, not multiplexing. if response #n hasn't been served, response #n+1 cannot be sent even if it's ready.

Comment: @irreputable:You are right on pipelining, but I disagree on your view `all connections share the same physical infrastructure that is serial in nature`.Because, the processes view is that the messages are already send and continues its job.The message may be still in the OS buffer waiting to be routed, but the processes view is that it has already been send and we can program on top of this using threads etc to increase processing and throughput

Comment: this is a very nice question and the discussion that followed is very valuable; it's a shame it only got a bunch of views, was it maybe more fitted to be migrated to programmers?

Comment: @guido:I have updated title and will see if I can find better tags.I would prefer a discussion here than Programmers SE to be honest

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. It is a bottleneck and a poor design. If the second TCP server can be multithreaded and handle more than one client at a time you should certainly implement it that way, same as another TCP server really (for example Tomcat itself), and use multiple connections to it.

Comment: 1)If the second server accepted multiple connections instead of having just one, as you seem to indicate, would it perhaps be better if the back end processing was done directly from the web app *in tomcat* in the first place instead of sending requests to other process as delegate? 2)@irreputable's comment seems in some sense reasonable, arguing that in the physical layer the messages will be send sequentially anyway, but do you think such a rationale could justify such design options?

Comment: :Am I misunderstand your answer?You are saying to handle everything in Tomcat?Not sure what you mean by `second TCP server`